# Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:ckeditor:zip:3.6.6.1.0

Tags: maven, grails, ckeditor, weceem

This has been a recurring problem from time to time even with no changes to `BuildConfig.groovy`.

I have the following in the plugins section of BuildConfig:

```
compile ":weceem:1.2"
```

This has a dependency to **ckeditor-3.6.6.1.0** which produced the error:

```
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:ckeditor:zip:3.6.6.1.0
```

I have worked around this before by placing `compile ":ckeditor:3.6.6.1.1"` in the same section as the code above as per [this bug issued](https://web.archive.org/web/20160514155942/http://jira.jcatalog.com/browse/WCM-887?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel), which did actually work for some time.

Now, however, I'm getting the same error again even with the reference to ckeditor 3.6.6.1.1.

Here is the output from dependency-report:

```
|Configuring classpath
|Downloading: org/grails/plugins/ckeditor/3.6.6.1.0/ckeditor-3.6.6.1.0.pom
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:ckeditor:zip:3.6.6.1.0 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:ckeditor:zip:3.6.6.1.0 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:ckeditor:zip:3.6.6.1.0 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:ckeditor:zip:3.6.6.1.0 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:ckeditor:zip:3.6.6.1.0
|Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
Error |
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:ckeditor:zip:3.6.6.1.0
|Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
Error |
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:ckeditor:zip:3.6.6.1.0
|Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
Error |
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:ckeditor:zip:3.6.6.1.0
|Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
Error |
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
Error |
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
Error |
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
.
|Environment set to development
.
build - Dependencies for the build system only (total: 33)
+--- xalan:serializer:2.7.1
+--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.3.7
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.4
|    \--- jline:jline:2.11
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.8.4
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant-trax:1.7.1
|    \--- net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.0.0
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant-junit:1.8.4
|    \--- org.codehaus.gant:gant_groovy1.8:1.9.6
|    \--- org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.3.0
|    \--- org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:1.11
+--- org.grails:grails-scripts:2.3.7
|    \--- org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0
|         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    \--- junit:junit:4.11
+--- org.grails:grails-docs:2.3.7
|    \--- org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer:R8
|    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-gdoc-engine:1.0.1
|    \--- com.lowagie:itext:2.0.8
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:138
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:138
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.grails.plugins:tomcat:7.0.52.1
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina-ant:7.0.52
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:7.0.52
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:7.0.52
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:7.0.52
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:7.0.52
|    \--- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:3.7.2
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:7.0.52


|Downloading: org/grails/plugins/ckeditor/3.6.6.1.0/ckeditor-3.6.6.1.0.pom
Error |
Error executing script DependencyReport: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.grails.plugins:weceem:zip:1.2 -> org.grails.plugins:ckeditor:zip:3.6.6.1.0 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Comment: OK, it seems that the problem is that there is no pom file for the 3.6.6.1.0 version of ckeditor at http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/ckeditor/3.6.6.1.0/ (contrast with 3.6.6.1.1, which has pom and several other files in addition to the zip here: http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/ckeditor/3.6.6.1.1/). Since weceem is looking for the 3.6.6.1.0 version it fails with "Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:ckeditor:zip:3.6.6.1.0" Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: Did you try to change the BuildConfig of the plugin ? (probably not recommended, but the difference 3.6.6.1.0 and 3.6.6.1.1 is probably not a big refactoring)

Comment: Yes, in fact I just ended up placing the 3.6.6.1.1 zip and pom in my local repo and changed all the 3.6.6.1.1s to 3.6.6.1.0s which seems to have made Grails happy. It's working now, but it's a really clunky workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the latest version of Weceem, **weceem-1.3-M1**. Also, pay attention that in `BuildConfig.groovy` we need to have additional repository:

```
mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
```

In the latest release we have plugin `ckeditor-4.4.1.0`.